# How to call functions with getattr in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror, axis, getattribute

I am trying to implement this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12025554/7718153
for matplotlib, but something goes wrong.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if condition1:
    q='plot'
elif condition2:
    q='logy'
elif condition3
    q='loglog'

m = globals()['plt']()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

plot_function = getattr(m, q) #it doens't make it to this line
```

I want it to do this:

```
if condition1:
    plt.plot(...)
elif condition2:
    plt.logy(...)
elif condition3:
    plt.loglog(...)
```

Does anyone know what I do wrong?

Edit: I am sorry, I had my code in the wrong order. It's fixed now.

Edit2:

This is the code where it origionally came from:

```
def plot(self):
    assert self.plotgraph == True
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 40})
    plt.figure(figsize=(150, 70))
    plt.suptitle('alpha = '+str("{0:.2f}".format(self.alpha)))


    j=len(self.seeds)
    for k in range(9*j):
        plt.subplot(3,3*j,k+1)
        g=k%(3*j)
        if k<3*j:
            q='plot'
        elif 3*j<=k<6*j:
            q='logy'
        elif 6*j<=k:
            q='loglog'
        m = globals()['plt']()
        plot_function = getattr(m, q)
        if g<2*j:
            for i in range(j):
                if (2*i)<=g%j*2<(2*(i+1)):
                    seed_type=' seed: '+ str(i+1)
                    seed=(i+1)
        else:
            for i in range(j):
                if g%j == i:
                    seed_type=' seed: '+ str(i+1)
                    seed=(i+1)

        if g<2*j:
            if g%2==0:
                set_type=' train-set'
                plot_function(np.array(self.index),np.array(self.plotlist[seed*2+0]))
            else:
                set_type=' test-set'
                plot_function(np.array(self.index),np.array(self.plotlist[seed*2+1]))
        else:
            set_type=' train-test dist'
            plot_function(np.array(self.index),np.array(self.plotlist[seed*2+0]-np.array(self.plotlist[seed*2+1])))

        plt.grid(True)
        plt.title(q+set_type+seed_type)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("plot1() " +str(self.nodes[1])+' hidden nodes, alpha='+ str("{0:.2f}".format(self.alpha)) + '.png')
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m = globals()['plt']()` is the same thing as `plt()`.  `plt` is a module so it isn't callable.  I think you want:

```
m = globals()['plt']
plot_function = getattr(m, q)
plot_function()  # call this one!
```

With that said... This design seems needlessly complex.  Why not:

```
if condition1:
    plt.plot()
elif condition2:
    plt.logy()
elif condition3:
    ...
```

Comment: It throws the error when I try to define m.
It is part of a bigger loop. I'll update my origional post.